# What is y * width + x from matrix class two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I'm kinda confused of how this statement works `this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y));`

```
class Matrix { 
    constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) { this.width = width; this.height = height; this.content = [];
//console.log(this.content);

for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) { 
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y); 
    console.log(this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y));
    } 
} 
} 

get(x, y) { return this.content[y * this.width + x]; } set(x, y, value) { this.content[y * this.width + x] = value; } }
 

class MatrixIterator { constructor(matrix) { this.x = 0; this.y = 0; this.matrix = matrix; } next() { if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true}; let value = {x: this.x, y: this.y, value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)};

this.x++; if (this.x == this.matrix.width) { this.x = 0; this.y++; } return {value, done: false}; } }

Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return new MatrixIterator(this); };
    
//We can now loop over a matrix with for/of. 

let matrix = new Matrix(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
console.log(matrix);
 for (let {x, y, value} of matrix) { console.log(x, y, value);
  }


    // → 0 0 value 0,0 
   // → 1 0 value 1,0 
  // → 0 1 value 0,1 
 // → 1 1 value 1,1
```

Comment: It's a one dimensional array describing a matrix. To access the appropriate `row` you multiply `y` by the width of the matrix, then add `x` to access the correct column.

Comment: `this.content` in Class `Matrix` seems to be a one dimensional array, with keys resulting from `y * width + x`.

Comment: pilchard, I get same result if I multiply y * height ?

Answer (score 0):

To identify each element of a matrix you need to use an index obviously , here the writer of the book you where you found this, chose this approach to do it :

```
y * this.width + x
```

This allows you to access a determined element of your Matrix while identifient all elements and guarantees that nothing will overlap .

Alternatively you can use :
`[y + '_' + x]` this does exactly the same purpus of `y * this.width + x` ,
but converting to string and concatenation uses loops for something that could be done by simply 2 operations ! `y * this.width` and `result + x` .
Here is a rewrite of your code with my way of indexing :

```js
class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = {};//you need this for string keys !
    //console.log(this.content);

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y +'_'+ x] = element(x, y);
        console.log((this.content[y +'_'+ x] = element(x, y)));
      }
    }
  }

  get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y +'_'+ x];
  }
  set(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y +'_'+ x] = value;
  }
}

class MatrixIterator {
  constructor(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }
  next() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return { done: true };
    let value = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y),
    };

    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return { value, done: false };
  }
}

//We can now loop over a matrix with for/of.

let matrix = new Matrix(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
console.log('Matrix formed is : ',matrix);
```

Comment: Here is an alternative hard and efficient way to do it . You can multiply by prime numbers to identify a dimension because they never overlap too. Exactly like the hash function in java . You need to search more aboute it because it's a very interesting topic … and it's related to this .

Comment: I think it **Always** works , if you want to store 2d in 1d array !